# How to Add Bootstrap glyphicons to Woocommerce Checkout Input Fields?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have narrowed down the code to this filter so far (found this in another SO answer):

```
//Checkout page editor bootstrap
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'addBootstrapGlyphs' );
function addBootstrapGlyphs($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as &$fieldset) {
        foreach ($fieldset as &$field) {
            // if you want to add the form-group class around the label and the input
            $field['class'][] = 'input-group'; 
            // add form-control to the actual input
            $field['input_class'][] = 'form-control';
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

That sets my form and input elements. Now to add glyphicons, I tried reading from $fields but I just can't seem to get a good handle to something that will let me add a *span* element before the *input*. Glyphicon needs this:

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
```

jQuery let's me do it this way:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery('#billing_last_name_field').prepend('<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>');
                    });
                </script>
```

but there has to be a better, more performant way to build the page with this in place already. I want to do this in php, so the checkout pageload remains fast. Please help. I come from a world of Java.

tl;dr: How to add a glyphicon to woocommerce checkout input boxes from https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1920

---

Part 2

making progress w.r.t the above question using something like this:

```
// define the woocommerce_form_field_<type> callback 
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_type( $field, $key, $args, $value ) { 
    $field = str_replace('<input','<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input',$field);
    return $field; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( "woocommerce_form_field_email", 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_type', 10, 4 );
```

I know, that is not the right glyph. However, the next hurdle is to edit the html. Like Mithc mentioned in a comment below, I will now try to do this more elegantly with some type of DOM handling code.

So my follow-up question is, how do I add a DOM element the proper way with php? This time, I am looking for something like,

1. Convert string to DOM for processing
2. read some attributes from the `<p>` or `<input>`
3. Determine the type of glyph i should use
4. Add my span
5. Convert DOM back to string for return

Any elegant ways to do this, or is str_replace() good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's no filter/action that allows you to modify the forms in that way. You can follow the clue of how the forms are built by checking the [`/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php) and [`/includes/wc-template-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1918).

### Solution #1: Pure CSS

You could use CSS pseudo elements to add icons to the fields but due to the layout of the form, playing around with `::before` and `::after` could make the responsiveness a nightmare. But here's an example:

```
.form-row#billing_company_field {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2.8em;
}

.form-row#billing_company_field::before {
    content: '';
    width: 2.8em;
    height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #2d2e34;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.form-row#billing_company_field::after {
    content: "\e139";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    /* Excluding position styling */
}
```

But as I mentioned before, the responsiveness could be a little bit like... A headache. But totally possible.

### Solution #2: Template Override

WooCommerce allows you to [override templates via themes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). The only thing you have to do is to create a `template` folder in your theme's root folder.

For instance, if your theme's folder is `my-store`, you should have `my-store/woocommerce`. To override the template parts that contain the checkout form, you should have:

```
my-store/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

and

```
my-store/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php
```

Then you can modify any markup there. Just keep in mind that sometimes they update the templates, so keep an eye on them for big changes to keep them up to date too.

### Solution #3: DOMDocument() *[Update]*

If you have the markup of each field on the filter, you can modify the output HTML with the [`DOMDocument()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) methods. Here's an example:

```php
// Let's say this is the HTML coming from the filter.
$field = '<p class="form-row validate-required">';
  $field .= '<input type="text">...';
$field .= '</p>';

// Create a DOM Object of $field. LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED and LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD will help to prevent doctype, html and body tags being inserted at the end.
$field_object = new DOMDocument();
$field_object->loadHTML( $field, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

// Select the wrapper of the input (`<p>`) and the input (`<input />`) to know where to insert the glyph (between them).
$wrapper = $field_object->getElementsByTagName( 'p' )->item( 0 );
$input = $field_object->getElementsByTagName( 'input' )->item( 0 );

// Create the glyphicon HTML.
$glyph = $field_object->createDocumentFragment();
$glyph->appendXML( '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>' );

// Insert the glyphicon HTML.
$wrapper->insertBefore( $glyph, $input );
```

The example above will get you:

```
<p class="form-row validate-required">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input type="text">...
</p>
```

To load attributes you can use [`getAttribute( $attribute_name )`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)
 on the DOMElement (like the `$wrapper` and `$input` objects). And, to determine the glyphicon you have to use, you could get the class of the `$wrapper` and determine the class of the glyphicon based on it. For instance, if the `$wrapper` contains the class `user`, then glyphicon's class should be `glyphicon glyphicon-user` which you can easily insert when you create the glyphicon HTML.

Comment: **Some mistakes in this answer:** The folder in the theme function has to be renamed **"woocommerce"** … so the path is `my-active-theme/woocommerce/checkout/…` but not `my-store/templates/checkout/…`. Additionally **fields doesn't appear in the templates.** So this **will not work**. You need to use hooks for that.

Comment: You're right, I corrected the answer on the folder name. Do you know what is the appropriate hook to achieve what OP is asking? Because it seems like there's no hook for the field HTML output.

Comment: Hi guys. Any ideas around modifying $field? The source tells me that $field is what is holding all that html. I have a handle to $field in my custom filter. how do I modify more than attributes on $field, or probably on $fieldset? Not sure which one.

Comment: If the `$field` variable contains the field HTML, you could use  [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to modify the output within the filter.

Comment: I made some progress w.r.t this. Thanks for the ideas. I have updated the question, please take a look if possible.